# Are "latex fruit intolerance/syndrome" and "histamine intolerance" related or otherwise two names for the same problem?

Tags: allergy, sensitivity-intolerance, histamine, latex

I have an intolerance to bananas and avocados without a doubt.  I get bowel cramps, bloating, and if I eat way too much of those foods, some mild topical itching on my skin.

My research for latex food intolerance and histamine intolerance clearly indicates bananas and avocados as the ***worst foods for both*** of these intolerances which caused me to wonder if they aren't the same thing.  I have also read that our bodies may interpret a structurally-similar chemical (chitinase) in the latex fruit family as actually being a histamine even though it isn't.

My question is, are these two intolerances actually the same thing, are they both simply related to histamine intolerances, or are they, in fact, two separate intolerances altogether?

Below I Google-searched "histamine intolerance chitinase".  None of the information I have found specifically clarifies that they are either different or simply two names for the same, or otherwise, very similar or related problems.  My results are inconclusive, and before I proceed to solve my problem by avoiding foods, I want to be sure I am avoiding the correct set of foods.

[image: Google Search]